# Java - add a text file to an ArrayList<Double>

Tags: java, arraylist

I have two questions:

1. I have a text file named numbers2.txt that displays (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10). How do I store those numbers to an ArrayList? I am fairly certain that you must use the Double.parseDouble(string s) method, but I am unfamiliar with this method.
2. The point of this program is to randomly select an operator from my ArrayList, then compute the problem with two random numbers. For the 
   if-statement what would I put instead of the operator?

here is my code:

```
String operator;
double answer;
Random rand = new Random();
ArrayList<String> myArray = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Double> doubles = new ArrayList<Double>();

public void CreateArrayList() {
     myArray.add("add");
     myArray.add("subtract");
     myArray.add("multiply");
     myArray.add("divide");
     myArray.add("remainder");
     myArray.add("greater than");
     myArray.add("less than");
     myArray.add("max");
     myArray.add("min");
     myArray.add("power");
     try {
            FileReader inFile = new FileReader("data/numbers2.txt");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inFile);

            scanner.close();
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();}
    }
{

}

public void showOperations() {

    double x = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
    double y = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
    int z = rand.nextInt(myArray.size());
    if(operator == "add") {
    answer = (x+y);
    System.out.println(x + " "+ z +" "+y+ "= "+ answer);
    }
} }
```

and this is my main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Operator op = new Operator();
        op.CreateArrayList();
        op.showOperations();
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Funny, I saw someone else with this exact homework assignment on here yesterday.

Comment: Where do you  "...randomly select an operator from my ArrayList"?

Comment: int z  = rand.nextInt(myArray.size());

Comment: "but I am unfamiliar with this method"? I don't think this is acceptable. I think you should research the docs and read other similar questions to try and find out how it works. Help should only be sought when all other paths are exhausted and not as an easy shortcut way to the answer.

Comment: What is happening that qualifies as undesired behavior? I see an objective, but no problem listed

Answer (score 0):

You close your Scanner directly after opening it. That is a pointless move. Try actually using to read the file. Also, use a [`finally`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html)  block to close the scanner in case there  is an exception:

```
Scanner scanner = null;
try {
     FileReader inFile = new FileReader("data/numbers2.txt");
     scanner = new Scanner(inFile);

     while(scanner.hasNextDouble){
         doubles.add(scanner.nextDouble());
     }   
} catch (Exception ex) {
     ex.printStackTrace();}
} finally {
     if(scanner != null) {
        scanner.close();
     }
}
```

As for the operator part, you cannot just get a random index, you  must also retrieve the element from that index:

```
int z = rand.nextInt(myArray.size());
// Get the element
operator = myArray.get(z);

switch (operator) {
case "add": {
    answer = (x + y);
    System.out.println(x + " + " + y + " = " + answer);
}
case "subtract": {
    answer = (x - y);
    System.out.println(x + " - " + y + " = " + answer);
}
case "multiply": {
    answer = (x * y);
    System.out.println(x + " * " + y + " = " + answer);
}
// and so on...
default:
    System.out.println(x + ", " + y);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, do you think you can help me on the 2nd part of my question?